# How do I disable a component through a condition?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I have a condition `(isOnFullDomain())` that returns `true`, if I am in this condition, the Component can't load.

This is the code i am using:

```
import Component from 'components/Component';

useEffect(() => {
    Component();
    if (isOnFullDomain()) {
      console.log('remove Component');
    }
  }, [path]);
```

I really need to remove the component once it's loaded, if I load it once, it's showing up on the screen.

I need something similar to:

```
if (isOnFullDomain()) {
  Component().remove;
}
```

Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to achieve that by using JSX, rather than react hooks - usually hooks are move towards data management, react to some value updates and do something about it.

In this case I imagine you have a `render` method that uses your `Component`. Hence something like this would make the `Component` not appear in the page.

```
import Component from 'components/Component';
// ...
const shouldRenderComponent = !isOnFullDomain();

return (
  {shouldRenderComponent && <Component />
);
```

*Sidenote: if you don't want to load the `Component` code internally, then you might want to have a look at the [import statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) and bundle splitting in order to "lazy load" that component.*

Comment: Thanks!! But I really need to remove the component once it's loaded, if I load it once, it's showing up on the screen.

Comment: Oh, I think I might get your problem. How does your `isOnFullDomain` look like? Ideally, it should be a React hook so that when the URL updates your wrapper component would trigger a re-render and make the `Component` appear/disappear based on the computed value of `isOnFullDomain()`. Maybe you're missing that dynamic behavior on `isOnFullDomain()`?

Answer (score 0):

In the component where you are rendering this component, you could conditionally render it, by doing something like this.

```
return(...
{!isOnFullDomain() && <ComponentToBeRendered/>}
...
)
```